# How to store the output of a loop in a variable? Python 2,7

Tags: python-2.7, variables, for-loop, output

Everyone

I want to store 40,000 "1" into a variable.
example:

V = 11111111111111111111.....

for i in range 40000:
            print V

1
1
1
1
1

I would like to store this into a variable as listed above:

v=1111111

the only thing i can think of is listing the file 111111 and storing it to a variable but that's just absurd, there got to be  a more efficient means

Comment: Do you accept v to be a string of 40k consecutive 1's?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the variable you desire by adding the sum of `10 ^ i`; where `i` is `0` through `40,000` inclusive. Although I'm not completely certain the resulting value is completely accurate.

```
>>> x = 0
>>> for i in range(40000): x += 10 ** i
...
>>> len(str(x))
40000
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure I'm reading this correctly but you want a variable that has 40k "1" in a row?

You can make a string and concatenate each iteration of "1" to it.

The following link has 6 different methods

[string concatenation](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/)